# Getting parents, children and meta in one query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently constructing a page of custom post type and their children. The page needs the meta of the parent and also of the children. To build the HTML I first get all the parents and then loop through each parent, retrieve the children and their meta, and add this data to the object containing the parents.

This means that I'm making one database call to get all the parents and then **another** database call **for each parent**.

Is there a native way to do this in WordPress? A way that will output a single object? An object with each parent, its meta, its children and their meta?

And do this without having to make multiple database calls?

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: Thanks! Can you pop that down below so I can accept it? Maybe you can let me know if this can be done with a custom SQL query too as that's not up my alley.